# $5-$Sylow subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$?

Tags: group-theory

Give  example of a $5-$Sylow subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$ ?

My attempt : $5-$Sylow subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)= 5^{3(3-1)/2}=125$

Comment: A duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2042902/11619)?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867683/sylow-p-groups-in-gl-3-bbb-f-p?rq=1).